# How to map multiple key combo to another multiple key combo in keyd on Linux?

Tags: keymapping

Configuration file where I tried one line at a time.

```
[main]
leftmeta+tab = leftcontrol+leftmeta+right 
#leftcontrol+leftmeta+right = leftmeta+tab
#leftcontrol+tab = macro(leftcontrol+leftmeta+right)
```

None of what I've tried works or makes any difference on my machine. I've also run `sudo keyd reload` every time.

The documentation at `man keyd` is a little bit confusing but from what I understand, this operation should work with `macro()`.

---